# File System Mapping on Azure Server

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I have a windows Azure server where I want to mount a file mapping. Below code works fine when I try it on my local windows machine. But it says `Access Denied` when try the same on `Azure Windows Server`. What am I missing here?

```
$acctKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<account_key>" -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Azure\<account_username>", $acctKey

New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server.name\files" -Credential $credential -Persist
```

P.S. It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) that I do have the access.

Comment: Without giving away your real credentials or real storage account name, can you please edit your PowerShell command to be more accurate, parameter-wise? With it abbreviated the way it is (and without seeing how you set up the credentials ahead of time), it's difficult, if not impossible, to  help spot the issue. Also, when you edit your question, please include the full error output as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure error messages are not helpful at all. I had the same issue when I try to debug an app I deployed to Azure. Similar issue here, that is all it says `Access Denied`. No other error message at all. Anyways, I have updated the question with the all the commands I have running to `Azure PowerShell`.

Comment: What, specifically, do you have for "`\\server.name\files`" ?

Comment: `\\<storage_accountname>.file.core.windows.net\<file_share_name>`. I don't think there is anything wrong with the way I am using the command, because it works fine on my local windows machine.

Comment: Do you get the same message with `\\<storage_accountname>.file.core.windows.net`?

Comment: @Andrew, yes...

Comment: And can you, from that power console, access that folder as well? Like running a dir command on that path?

Comment: Access what folder, again? `<file_share_name>` folder?

Comment: @HafizTemuri What version of your Azure VM? Could you show me how do you create the `Credential`?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT, Windows 10 and I have updated the question.

Comment: @HafizTemuri Does the storage account and Azure VM in the same region?

Comment: How can I check that and also how to make sure that they are?

Comment: @HafizTemuri just check it via Azure portal, you can find the location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164668/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-hafiz-temuri).

Comment: Could you try to use `map network drive` via GUI?

Comment: I don't know to do that with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to mount azure file share with command prompt:

```
net use Z: \\jasonvmdisks304.file.core.windows.net\jasonshare yjya1gkE0TK0lqx/OUh1kD4fxdhCLDjcOW6XPSF6Y4jyCxxMd45eFEvYRzKp8CMRjRpuz38RISA49qXWw3wKA== /user:Azure\jasonvmdisks304
```

If it still not work, could you please check the event view to find the log, and post it here.

Comment: if I try with azure console, it still saying `Access Denied`, but when I try it with `PowerShell`, it says `Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters.`, `net use Z: \\jasonvmdisks304.file.core.windows.net\jasonshare yjya1gk ...`, `+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
`, `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument`

Comment: I checked the `Activity logs`, nothing is there. And I can't find the event view logs anywhere.

Comment: @HafizTemuri Have you try to use administrator to mount it? for test, could you please mount this file share to another Azure VM in the same vnet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if resolved so will chime in.  One question, if the client is in a different Azure region (e.g. on premise or elsewhere) then SMB3.0 is required, else, SMB2.1 (if in the same region) is allowed.  This is a security feature.